# NSOpenGLContext + YUV to RGB Shader + Incorrect Render

Tags: cocoa, opengl, core-video

I'm rendering YUV frames using NSOpenGLContext, OpenGL and a Shader to perform YUV to RGB conversion on the GPU.

The output is not what is expected. From the image below what might be the problem?

[image: Render Problem]

Comment: I'm guessing something in shader or texture upload.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the YUV texture data you are uploading is in the wrong format... At the very least it is offset by around 16 bytes (are you accidentally uploading a header before the raw YUV data?).

It seems like the format of the Luminance itself is probably ok, but the Chrominance is being decoded wrong.

Hope that's some help!